# Uncaught TypeError - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, typeerror

I get that error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
initJavaScript

File:
http://www.radiomrs.pl/wp-content/plugins/pierres-wordspew/ajax_shout.js
91 line

Why it's something like that?
On site http://radiomrs.pl shoutbox work nice.

Comment: This happens in cases where the element you trying to retrieve and assign the handler to does not exist (yet) or you really don't know what you are doing and did not even initialize the variable you are trying to set `onclick` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trust your browser... ;)

Go to line 91 of ajax_shout.js and you'll find:

```
document.getElementById('submitchat').onclick = sendComment;
```

document.getElementById('submitchat') is null, that is there's no such element in your DOM, or the element has not been loaded yet when the script tries to access it.

Comment: But how i can repair that? I guessed that but i don't know much javascript.. it's some plugin to wordpress, that why i write.

Comment: @Dominik: Well, you have to make sure that element exists. Which means (a) check there exists an element with ID `submitchat` in your HTML and (b) execute your JavaScript after the element was created.

Comment: Easy ! Thanks! Now i understand all!